# Cannot train Transformer to add 1

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network

I am experimenting with a transformer model and am trying to teach it a single task that adds 1 to the input. It will take in a batch of random numbers X and predict X + 1. Here is my code:

Does anyone have any idea why the loss never goes down? The transformer has 1 head, 1 dimension and 10 encoders. I tried a single neural network with one neuron and the exact same hyperparameters and it was able to learn the +1 function. But once I swap out my single layer perceptron FFN with a Transformer, I get a massive loss that fluctuates without ever going down.

```py
import torch
from torch import nn
import torch.optim as optim
    
device = torch.device('cuda:0' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
batch=1024
    
class MyModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.tgt = torch.rand(1, batch, 1).to(device)
        self.trans = nn.Transformer(nhead=1, num_encoder_layers=10, d_model=1)
    def forward(self, x):
        y = self.trans(x, self.tgt)
        return y

model = MyModel()
model.to(device)
    
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.01)
    
running_loss = 0.0
upper = 10000000
for epoch in range(1000):
    training = torch.randint(low=0, high=upper, size=(batch,)).float().to(device) #Get batch of random numbers
    training = torch.unsqueeze(training, 1)
    training = torch.unsqueeze(training, 0) #Get the input data into the form specified in the docs (aka S,B,E)
    labels = training + 1
    labels.to(device) # Learn to add 1
    
    optimizer.zero_grad()
        
    outputs = model(training)
    loss = nn.MSELoss()(outputs, labels)
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    
    # print statistics
    running_loss += loss.item()
    print(f'[{epoch + 1}] loss: {running_loss:.3f}')
    running_loss = 0.0
    
print('Finished Training')
```

--Edit---
Even with this highly simplified transformer I still get bad performance:         self.trans = nn.Transformer(nhead=1, num_encoder_layers=1, d_model=1, dim_feedforward=1)

It must be an implementation bug somewhere because this is basically a FFN now

Comment: It feels to me that transformer isn't the correct tool to solve this. Your input is a number, and you are feeding that directly into the transformer layer without any embedding, so your input dimension is 1, this creates very limited feature embedding and your transformer/attention layer isn't going to get much information about your input. If you print the model architecture, you see a bunch of `in_features=1` and a number of layers mapping that to a `out_features=2048`, which isn't sounding at all. It would probably make more sense if you are embedding the input's digits.

Comment: @TYZ I set dim_feedforward=1 and I see the same problem